# Sum chars from strings & print biggest string (java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, char

I'm stuck at some interesting task. I have 3 strings (**hello**, **heavy** & **word**). Need to calculate sum of each wold and print the biggest world and sum. For calculating - a = 1, z = 26. So hello = 50, heavy = 61 & word = 60. The biggest string is "heavy" and I need to print it like "heavy, 61". I found code who calculate chars from one string:

```
String[] words = {"hello", "heavy", "word"};

String str = "abc";
int sum = 0;

for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
        sum += 1 + ch - 'a';
    }
}
System.out.printf("%s %d%n", str, sum); //the result is abc, 6
```

**The result from this code is:** abc, 6

The question is, how to calculate all words and how to print the biggest one? I can write sum for each word and calculate it later, but in my task words are random from console. **Scanning isn't problem.**

**Edit:** All words are lowercase letters.

Comment: Would the value of `a` and `A` be the same?

Comment: You are suppose to create a method that does it for a parameter. Then you call the method in a loop.

Comment: all words will be lowercase a-z

Comment: Tip: Lowercase a-z are called lowercase [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) letters. They have the properties of needing only one UTF-16 code unit to encode and of being consecutive in UTF-16. A Java [`char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) is a UTF-16 code unit. (That makes your mapping simple `1 + ch - 'a'`.) UTF-16 is one of several character encodings for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
String[] words = { "hello", "heavy", "word" };

int biggestSum = 0;
String biggestWord = null;

for (String word : words) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (char ch : word.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
            sum += 1 + ch - 'a';
        }
    }

    if (sum > biggestSum) {
        biggestSum = sum;
        biggestWord = word;
    }

    System.out.printf("%s %d%n", word, sum);
}

System.out.printf("Biggest word: %s %d%n", biggestWord, biggestSum);
```

Here we loop through every word in `words`, and keep count of the `sum` of each word. After the `sum` has been calculated we can check if the `sum` of the current `word` is bigger than the biggest word found so far, and if that's the case we override `biggestWord`.

Comment: Thanks. This is very easy and short way for the task. I'll read more about "for (String word : words) {"

Comment: `for (String word : words)` is a simpler, tighter concept for a loop. It's easier to write and read and translate to/from the problem domain. Verbalize it like this: "for each word in words".

Answer (score 1):

For every word, calculate the word sum, and update a variable which holds the largest sum. For example:

```
int largestSum;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfWords.Length (); i++)
{
    // calculate the sum of the current word
    int currentWordSum = 0; 
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfWords[i].Length ();j++)
    {
        currentWordSum += (int)(arrayOfWords[j]);
        if (currentWordSum > largestSum)
        {
            largestSum = currentWordSum;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println (largestSum);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a useful way for calculate.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it easily using a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is *String* and the value is the *weight*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = { "hello", "heavy", "word" };
    Map<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        hmap.put(words[i], 0);
    }

    hmap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        int tot = 0;
        for (char c : k.toCharArray()) {
            tot = tot + (c - 'a' + 1);
        }
        hmap.put(k, tot);
    });
 }
```

Now you can iterate over this map to find the *heaviest* string.

**EDIT :**

Without using map :

```
    String highString= "";
    int highest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        int tot = 0;
        for (char c : words[i].toCharArray()) {
            tot = tot + (c - 'a' + 1);
            if (highest < tot) {
                highest = tot;
                highString = words[i];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(highString + "," + highest);
```

Comment: We don't really need map. We can use single iteration which will hold current max word and its score. If new word will be bigger simply replace max.

Comment: Agreed. Added another alternative.

Comment: Thanks for this option. In my beginning course hasn't learn for HashMaps, but this example is good way to self-education :)